# Placing footnote mark before or after punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, writing, academic-writing

I am writing a research paper. I need to add a footnote. Should I place the footnote mark/superscript before or after "full stop"?

For example:

1. The placement of footnote: style A<sup>here</sup>.
2. The placement of footnote: style B.<sup>here</sup>

Which of the above usages is correct?

Comment: The superscript notation is from HTML:  <sup>number</sup>  (<sub> also works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will help with foot marks

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/footnote-marks-at-end-of-a-sentence

---

1.. this is some text1. (before the full stop)

2.. this is some text.1 (after the full stop)

If you want the footnote reference to belong to the entire sentence, then the second method is correct. However, if you want the footnote to apply only to the word text, then the first is correct.

---

However be careful in your paper somethings should be  referenced or appendixes as opposed to foot marked as per se.

> References
> At the end of the report or paper (after the conclusions section or chapter), you include a
> reference list, in which you list all literature, to which you have referred to in your main
> text. Conversely, all references in the reference list should appear in the main text. The
> reference list is not a chapter, so it is not numbered. Just as the summary, the reference
> list is ordered in alphabetical order. For a correct formatting of the references in the
> main text and in the reference list, we refer to chapter 3.

> Appendices
> An appendix contains materials that would obscure the structure and message of the
> text if it is included in the main text. Examples include tables of all quantitative research
> results, examples of field observation forms, or computer code. All appendices should be
> given an appropriate title and numbered consecutively.

Comment: @ James K The poster and I have commented in another related post. I am relating to scientific writing where references should be Referenced at the end of the report or paper (after the conclusions section or chapter) not as footnotes. I have edited the answer to reflect your other comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing an article you should have a style guide that hopefully will tell you what to do in situations like this.  The fact is that different guides give different advice.

The [Chicago Manual of Style](https://research.wou.edu/c.php?g=551307&p=3785233) (CMS) uses footnotes for citations.  The footnote mark is placed before the punctuation and links to a reference<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1.</sup><sub>Chicago Manual of style, 17th Edition. (Chicago University Press) https://research.wou.edu/c.php?g=551307&p=3785233</sub>

On the other hand, the [Modern Language Association](https://www.scribendi.com/academy/articles/what_are_footnotes.en.html) (MLA) only uses footnotes for directing the reader to other pertinent information, not for citations,<sup>2</sup> and they instruct authors to place the mark after any commas or full-stops (but before — dashes)

<sup>2.</sup><sub>The MLA uses author-date style citations.</sub>

Some people recommend a "logical" style. Place the footnote mark after the punctuation if the note is pertinent to the whole sentence, and before if it is only relevant to part of it.

> We saw flying penguins.<sup>1</sup>

> We saw flying penguins<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1.</sup>This was while travelling around Nova Scotia.

<sup>2.</sup>... or perhaps awks